# Susan Foreman's Fate & Future

Tags: doctor-who

What happened to The Doctor's granddaughter, [Susan Foreman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Foreman)? What was her ultimate fate?

[image]

Is it possible that she'll make an appearance in the new (2005) Doctor Who?

Comment: Of course it's *possible*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Susan married a human in 22nd-century Earth.

She [helped him rebuild the Earth after a Dalek invasion](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dalek_Invasion_of_Earth#Flashpoint_.286.29), and except for a brief period in [*The Five Doctors*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Five_Doctors_(TV_story)) when she was scooped up by the Time Lords for a nefarious plan, she never again saw her grandfather on screen.

[We don't know when or how she died](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Susan_Foreman#Fate). If the Ninth Doctor included Susan [when he told Rose that his entire family died](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Father%27s_Day_(TV_story)) in the Last Great Time War, we don't know how she got back to Gallifrey.

There's not enough information to go on to say Susan *couldn't* return in New Who. Certainly [Carol Ann Ford](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Carole_Ann_Ford) is still alive and connected to *Doctor Who*; she did some work for Big Finish audio productions, some 50th anniversary special work, and made a cameo in [*The Five(ish) Doctors Reboot*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fiveish_Doctors_Reboot_(TV_story)).

Susan had some adventures in non-screen mediums, but they are contradictory and non-canon, so I won't go into them here.

Comment: Meh.  Beat me by seconds.  Ah, well.. +1 to you, then :)

Comment: I heard that 8 brought her back. And I think she's the TimeLady at this picture: http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/the-woman-end-of-time-part-2.jpg

Comment: @Michel Got a citation for that? Because [RTD has said](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Woman_(The_End_of_Time)) he wrote The Woman as the Doctor's mother, but acknowledged that she could be Susan--or Romana, or any other trustworthy Time Lady. I didn't consider that solid enough to include in the answer--a list of everyone who *could* be Susan is too open-ended and iterative a list for the SE format--but if you've got something more concrete I'd be delighted to add it in.

Comment: @BESW I agree with you, I just wanted to add it as a comment, since it's an assumption of my own. Maybe it'll help in the future, since the Time Lord/Lady are  now back to the scene.

Comment: @BESW - You may want to add some kind of reference to this answer.